# c# multithreading, parallel processing

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm pretty new to C#'s TPL and async/await approach.
What I need is copying file and computing it's hash while copying (to avoid double read source file). I've tried to write my own solution for this, but resulting code is awful and hardly maintainable, also it uses ManualResetEvent and C#'s *lock* as sync block, which is more similar to c# of 2000s, when only threads were available.
Here is the function:

```
private const int BufferSizeMib = 64;
private const int BuffersCount = 4;
public static async Task<byte[]> CopyUnbufferedAndComputeHashAsync(string filePath, string destinationPath, Action<double> progressCallback, bool allowSimultaneousIo)
{
    const FileOptions fileFlagNoBuffering = (FileOptions) 0x20000000;
    const FileOptions fileOptions = fileFlagNoBuffering | FileOptions.SequentialScan;

    const int chunkSize = BufferSizeMib * 1024 * 1024;

    var readBufferSize = chunkSize;
    readBufferSize += ((readBufferSize + 1023) & ~1023) - readBufferSize;

    using (HashAlgorithm sha = SHA1.Create())
    using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, readBufferSize, fileOptions))
    using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, readBufferSize, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
    {
        var length = sourceStream.Length;
        var toRead = length;

        var readSize = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Min(chunkSize, length));

        var buffer = new LightBuffer[BuffersCount];
        for (var i = 0; i < BuffersCount; ++i)
            buffer[i] = new LightBuffer(readSize) {Number = -1 * i};

        void Increment(ref int idx)
        {
            idx++;
            if (idx > BuffersCount - 1)
                idx = 0;
        }

        var locker = new object();

        var readTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var blockNum = 0;
            var readIdx = 0;
            while (toRead > 0)
            {
                var lightBuffer = buffer[readIdx];
                lightBuffer.WriteDone.WaitOne();
                lightBuffer.WriteDone.Reset();
                lightBuffer.Number = ++blockNum;

                if (allowSimultaneousIo)
                {
                    lightBuffer.Length = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(lightBuffer.Data, 0, readSize);
                    if (lightBuffer.Length == 0)
                        throw null;
                }
                else
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        lightBuffer.Length = sourceStream.Read(lightBuffer.Data, 0, readSize);
                        if (lightBuffer.Length == 0)
                        {
                            Debugger.Break();
                            throw null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                toRead -= lightBuffer.Length;

                lightBuffer.IsFinal = toRead == 0;
                lightBuffer.DataReady.Set();

                Increment(ref readIdx);
            }
        });

        var writeTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var writeIdx = 0;
            var run = true;
            var writeDone = 0L;
            while (run)
            {
                var lightBuffer = buffer[writeIdx];

                lightBuffer.DataReady.WaitOne();
                lightBuffer.DataReady.Reset();

                var hashTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (lightBuffer.IsFinal)
                    {
                        sha.TransformFinalBlock(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length);
                        run = false;
                    }
                    else
                        sha.TransformBlock(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length, null, 0);
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

                if (allowSimultaneousIo)
                {
                    await destinationStream.WriteAsync(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        destinationStream.Write(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length);
                    }
                }

                await hashTask;

                writeDone += lightBuffer.Length;

                lightBuffer.WriteDone.Set();

                progressCallback?.BeginInvoke((double) writeDone / length * 100d, ar => { }, null);

                Increment(ref writeIdx);
            }
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(readTask, writeTask);

        return sha.Hash;
    }
}

private class LightBuffer
{
    public LightBuffer(int size)
    {
        Data = new byte[size];
    }

    public byte[] Data { get; }

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public ManualResetEvent DataReady { get; } = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public ManualResetEvent WriteDone { get; } = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    public bool IsFinal { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

**BufferSizeMib** specifies how many bytes would I read/write/compute hash at once;

**BuffersCount** specifies how many buffers (of size BufferSizeMib) would I allocate in memory (to load slowest resource to 100%, e.g. to read next chunk while writing/hashing previous);

**allowSimultaneousIo**, if true, enables simultaneous write while read if BuffersCount > 1 (e.g. source and destination are on different physical drives, we can read next chunk while writing if target is slower and vice versa).

Can it be refactored to use purely async/await? Or maybe leverage TPL DataFlow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any way to make this code extendable? e.g. make hashing optional, and add/remove it when necessary or implement some other _file_chunk_processor_?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very complicated. You can refactor your code, for example to this form:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int BufferSizeMib = 64;
        private const int BuffersCount = 4;
        private static object locker = new object();

        private static void Increment(ref int idx)
        {
            idx++;
            if (idx > BuffersCount - 1)
            {
                idx = 0;
            }
        }

        private static async Task ReadAsync(long toRead, LightBuffer[] buffer, bool allowSimultaneousIo, FileStream sourceStream, int readSize)
        {
            var blockNum = 0;
            var readIdx = 0;

            while (toRead > 0)
            {
                var lightBuffer = buffer[readIdx];
                lightBuffer.WriteDone.WaitOne();
                lightBuffer.WriteDone.Reset();
                lightBuffer.Number = ++blockNum;

                if (allowSimultaneousIo)
                {
                    lightBuffer.Length = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(lightBuffer.Data, 0, readSize);
                    if (lightBuffer.Length == 0)
                    {
                        throw null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        lightBuffer.Length = sourceStream.Read(lightBuffer.Data, 0, readSize);
                        if (lightBuffer.Length == 0)
                        {
                            Debugger.Break();
                            throw null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                toRead -= lightBuffer.Length;

                lightBuffer.IsFinal = toRead == 0;
                lightBuffer.DataReady.Set();

                Increment(ref readIdx);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<byte[]> WriteAsync(LightBuffer[] buffer, bool allowSimultaneousIo, Action<double> progressCallback, long length, int readBufferSize, string destinationPath)
        {
            using (HashAlgorithm sha = SHA1.Create())
            using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, readBufferSize, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
            {
                var writeIdx = 0;
                var run = true;
                var writeDone = 0L;
                while (run)
                {
                    var lightBuffer = buffer[writeIdx];

                    lightBuffer.DataReady.WaitOne();
                    lightBuffer.DataReady.Reset();

                    var hashTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        if (lightBuffer.IsFinal)
                        {
                            sha.TransformFinalBlock(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length);
                            run = false;
                        }
                        else
                            sha.TransformBlock(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length, null, 0);
                    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

                    if (allowSimultaneousIo)
                    {
                        await destinationStream.WriteAsync(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lock (locker)
                        {
                            destinationStream.Write(lightBuffer.Data, 0, lightBuffer.Length);
                        }
                    }

                    await hashTask;

                    writeDone += lightBuffer.Length;

                    lightBuffer.WriteDone.Set();

                    progressCallback?.BeginInvoke((double)writeDone / length * 100d, ar => { }, null);

                    Increment(ref writeIdx);
                }

                return sha.Hash;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<byte[]> CopyUnbufferedAndComputeHashAsync(string filePath, string destinationPath, Action<double> progressCallback, bool allowSimultaneousIo)
        {
            const FileOptions fileFlagNoBuffering = (FileOptions)0x20000000;
            const FileOptions fileOptions = fileFlagNoBuffering | FileOptions.SequentialScan;

            const int chunkSize = BufferSizeMib * 1024 * 1024;

            var readBufferSize = chunkSize;
            readBufferSize += ((readBufferSize + 1023) & ~1023) - readBufferSize;

            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, readBufferSize, fileOptions))
            {
                var length = sourceStream.Length;
                var toRead = length;

                var readSize = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Min(chunkSize, length));

                var buffer = new LightBuffer[BuffersCount];
                for (var i = 0; i < BuffersCount; ++i)
                {
                    buffer[i] = new LightBuffer(readSize) { Number = -1 * i };
                }

                // execute tasks
                var readTask = ReadAsync(toRead, buffer, allowSimultaneousIo, sourceStream, readSize);
                var writeTask = WriteAsync(buffer, allowSimultaneousIo, progressCallback, length, readBufferSize, destinationPath);

                // await tasks
                await Task.WhenAll(readTask, writeTask);

                // return hash
                return writeTask.Result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class LightBuffer
    {
        public LightBuffer(int size)
        {
            Data = new byte[size];
        }

        public byte[] Data{ get; }
        public int Length{ get; set; }
        public ManualResetEvent DataReady{ get; } = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public ManualResetEvent WriteDone{ get; } = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        public bool IsFinal{ get; set; }
        public int Number{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please note: I have only refactored your code and not tested it for correct function. You should consider simplifying your code.

Comment: Reading and writing are two completely different functionalities. So it's only natural to put them into separate methods.

Comment: I also suggest to implement the buffer as a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a really nice solution for your problem, using `BlockingCollection`. `BlockingCollection` gives you a thread-safe queue and blocks `Add()` operations when the queue is full and `Take()` operations when the queue is empty.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const int writeBufferSize = 10;
        private const int hashBufferSize = 10;
        private const int blockSize = 512;

        private DataBlock ReadData(FileStream sourceStream, int count)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[count];
            var len = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);

            return new DataBlock { Buffer = buffer, Length = len };
        }

        private Task GetWriteTask(BlockingCollection<DataBlock> collection, string destinationPath)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                    while (!collection.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        var dataBlock = collection.Take();
                        destinationStream.Write(dataBlock.Buffer, 0, dataBlock.Length);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private Task GetHashTask(BlockingCollection<DataBlock> collection)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Here you have to call the hashing algorithm
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            });
        }

        private void ProcessData(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
        {
            // initialize blocking collections
            BlockingCollection<DataBlock> writeBuffer = new BlockingCollection<DataBlock>(writeBufferSize);
            BlockingCollection<DataBlock> hashBuffer = new BlockingCollection<DataBlock>(hashBufferSize);

            // create tasks for writing and hashing
            var writeTask = GetWriteTask(writeBuffer, destinationPath);
            var hashTask = GetHashTask(hashBuffer);

            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, blockSize))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // read data block
                    DataBlock dataBlock = ReadData(sourceStream, blockSize);

                    if (dataBlock.Length == 0)
                    {
                        // reading is finished
                        writeBuffer.CompleteAdding();
                        hashBuffer.CompleteAdding();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // add data to collections
                        writeBuffer.Add(dataBlock);
                        hashBuffer.Add(dataBlock);
                    }
                }
            }

            // wait until writing and hashing is finished
            Task.WaitAll(writeTask, hashTask);
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class DataBlock
    {
        public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but I didn't test it. And I didn't implement the hashing algorithm.